# Column definition incompatible with clustered column definition

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have created a cluster in Oracle

```
CREATE  CLUSTER myLovelyCluster (clust_id NUMBER(38,0))
SIZE 1024 SINGLE TABLE HASHKEYS 11;
```

Than a table for the cluster

```
 CREATE TABLE Table_cluster
CLUSTER myLovelyCluster (columnRandom)
AS SELECT * FROM myTable ;
```

the columnRandom is well defined as NUMBER(38,0) but why I am getting an error assuming incompatible column definition?

Thanks

Comment: myLovelyCluster  != myCluster3 .

Comment: opps! sorry I fixed it , but the issue remains

Comment: When you CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT * FROM myTable , what is the resultant date type of the clustering column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that columnRandom is number(38,0)? In oracle NUMBER != NUMBER(38,0)

Let's create two table.

```
create table src_table ( a number);
create table src_table2( a number(38,0));

select column_name,data_precision,Data_scale from user_tab_cols where table_name like 'SRC_TABLE%';
```

Result of query is. Definitions of column are different.

```
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| Column_name | Data_Precision | Data_scale |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| A           |                |            |
| A           |             38 |          0 |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

And if i try creat cluster for first table.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_cluster
CLUSTER myLovelyCluster (a)
AS SELECT * FROM src_table ;
```

`ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition`

For 2-nd every thing is ok.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_cluster
CLUSTER myLovelyCluster (a)
AS SELECT * FROM src_table2 ;
```

If you add cast into select. Execution also is correct.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_cluster CLUSTER myLovelyCluster  (a)
AS SELECT cast(a as number(38,0)) FROM src_table;
```

Comment: In oracle NUMBER != NUMBER(38,0) correct ! Also , for some weird reason It worked with Integer , no idea why but as you know in programmer life , whenever something work , we don't ask questions

Comment: For Integer answers is easy.  Subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38,0);