# How do I add a cluster on a composite key?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sqlplus, composite-key

I have created a cluster

```
create cluster abc_clus
(abc_key int)
;
```

and then created an index based on that cluster

```
create index abc_clus_idx
on cluster abc_clus;
```

I tried adding this cluster on these 4 tables for a *complex* join

```
 create table number1
(
    dateofbirth date,  
    Time timestamp(0), 
    IDnumber int not null,
    class varchar(7) not null, 
primary key (dateofbirth, Time, class))
cluster abc_clus(class);
```

and

```
  create table number2(
    tutornumber int not null,
    forename varchar2(20) not null,
 constraint number2 primary key (tutornumber))
       cluster abc_clus(tutornumber);
```

and

```
create table number3
(
constraint number3 primary key (Roomnumber),
Roomnumber int not null, 
xyz varchar(20))
cluster abc_clus(Roomnumber3);
```

and

```
create table number4
(
constraint class_pk primary key (classnumber),
classnumber int not null)
 cluster abc_clus(classnumber);
```

However, when I try this, I get this error:

> ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition

I'm wondering how the correct way would be to add the cluster on the composite key: firstname, lastname, address.

I am using SQL plus.

Thanks

Comment: You need define all columns in cluster table along with data types.

Comment: Im confused? do i need to make changes to the table i created?

Comment: Now I'm confused I thought you wanted composite key in cluster table.It all depends your requirements and tables involved.

Comment: Are there any other tables that share common column(s)? Why do you want create a cluster in the first place?.

Comment: Yes i will update the question to be more clear

Comment: Please see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477654/column-definition-incompatible-with-clustered-column-definition

Comment: Yes but im not sure how to implement it in my example, I'm just very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table column needs to be the same datatype as the cluster column. In your example, this works fine:

```
create table test1 (
  id int
) cluster abc_clus(id);
Table TEST1 created.
```

Even a composite key works, if the datatype matches:

```
create table test2 (
  a int,
  b int,
  primary key(a, b)
) cluster abc_clus(a);
Table TEST2 created.
```

However, if the datatype is different, you get your error message:

```
create table test3 (
  vc varchar2(7)
) cluster abc_clus(vc);
ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition
```

And the datatype has to be exactly the same, even `int` and `number` are not compatible:

```
create table test4 (
  n NUMBER
) cluster abc_clus(n);
ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition
```

EDIT:

You can even have composite clusters:

create cluster idc_clus (
   i int,
   d date
);

create index idc_clus_idx on cluster idc_clus;

create table test5 (
  i int,
  d date,
  primary key (i,d)
) cluster idc_clus(i, d);

Comment: I see what you mean. So is there any way i could create a composite key that consists of columns with 2 or more different data types and be able to create a cluster? would the only way for me to fix my example in my question to remove the table that contains a composite key and make sure that all the other tables have the same data type for the primary keys?

Comment: A primary key is a logical thing, you use it to identify the rows in a table. A cluster is a physical thing to speed up access to related data. Clusters are explained rather well in the [Concept Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-04AADD81-E5C2-498B-B857-DF2A37DD3520)

Comment: Yes but when we create the cluster we have to add this '(abc_key int)' , isn't this the key that identifies all the datatypes that will be used in the tables. Like when we link the cluster to the table?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the important bits are the datatypes. The names of the columns can differ, but the datatype needs to be the same.

Comment: As the documentation explains "The cluster key is the column or columns that the clustered tables have in common. For example, the employees and departments tables share the department_id column. You specify the cluster key when creating the table cluster and when creating every table added to the table cluster."

Comment: Ah so 1 cluster with the datatypes of (int)= Table(s) with the primary key of int. However, 1 cluster with a datatype of int = NOT work with a table(s) Number and int. Now, if i wanted to add a cluster to a composite key that has different datatypes, is there anyways to do so or is it impossible ?

Comment: No, you are mixing up primary keys and cluster keys. The first a logical things (information content), the second physical things (speed). Look at the example in Oracle's documentation. The tables employees and departments can share the department_id column in a cluster. This happens to be the primary key of departments, but not the primary key of employees.