# How do i add a cluster on a composite key with different datatypes?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sqlplus, composite-key

I have a few tables that I want to cluster however, I have boiled the problem down to this table. This is how I created my cluster:

```
create cluster xyz_clus
(xyz_key int,
date1 date,
time timestamp
);
```

This is how I added the index:

```
create index  xyz_clus_idx on cluster xyz_clus;
```

And this is the table i made:

```
 create table ABC
    (
    PRIMARY KEY (date1, time, number1),
    date1 date,  
    time timestamp(0), 
    number1 int not null,
    classnumber varchar(7) not null, 
    constraint timeslot_classnumber_fk Foreign Key (classnumber) references class (classnumber)
    )
      cluster xyz_clus(date1, time, number1);
```

However, no matter how hard I try I am receiving this error constantly

```
ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570454/how-do-i-add-a-cluster-on-a-composite-key), the datatypea need to match exactly. The following code works:

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
  date1       DATE,  
  time        TIMESTAMP, 
  number1     INT NOT NULL,
  classnumber VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (date1, time, number1),  
  CONSTRAINT timeslot_classnumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (classnumber) 
             REFERENCES CLASS (classnumber)
) CLUSTER xyz_clus(number1, date1, time);
Table ABC created
```

However, this leads to an error because it uses `TIMESTAMP(0)` in the table and `TIMESTAMP` in the cluster:

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
  date1       DATE,  
  time        TIMESTAMP(0), 
  number1     INT NOT NULL,
  classnumber VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (date1, time, number1),  
  CONSTRAINT timeslot_classnumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (classnumber) 
             REFERENCES CLASS (classnumber)
) CLUSTER xyz_clus(number1, date1, time);
ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition
```

Likewise, the order of the columns in a composite key matter. The following query has the correct `TIMESTAMP`, but the order of the columns in the table is `DATE, TIMESTAMP, INT`, and in the cluster `INT, DATE, TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
  date1       DATE,  
  time        TIMESTAMP, 
  number1     INT NOT NULL,
  classnumber VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (date1, time, number1),  
  CONSTRAINT timeslot_classnumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (classnumber) 
             REFERENCES CLASS (classnumber)
) CLUSTER xyz_clus(date1, time, number1);
ORA-01753: column definition incompatible with clustered column definition
```